# splitting strings in to seperate columns in a dataframe

Tags: python-3.x, string, pandas, dataframe

[image]

so i have a string like this

```
{'city': 'Boston', 'line': '101 Sawyer Ave Unit 2', 'postal_code': '02125', 'state_code': 'MA', 'state': 'Massachusetts', 'county': 'Suffolk', 'fips_code': '25025', 'lat': 42.313099, 'lon': -71.062912, 'neighborhood_name': 'Dorchester'}
```

each row in my dataframe currently has a "address" value like that in a dictionary looking string, need help breaking this down to separate columns. focused on the address column in the image

each key will be a column name, and the contents will belong to their respective rows.
the photo attachted shows what the data looks like

Comment: there is no photo attached. You wanna convert the dictionary to a dataframe?

Comment: try this : `pd.io.json.json_normalize(df.address[0])`